# python- find the file with the highest value in the file name using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I have some folders and in each folder is a list of files like below:

file-Test01-summary.xlsm

file-Test02-summary.xlsm

file-Test03-summary.xlsm

the number of files can be different! in each folder could be 3 to 5 file!
I need a code to find the file with highest test number.

It could be great if the code will be write with `os.walk()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the name of the file and split it as below to filter the integers.

I didn't write the code in os.walk(), but i hope this gives you a start.

```py
#List with all file names
from os import walk

FilenameList = ['file-Test01-summary.xlsm', 'file-Test02-summary.xlsm', 'file-Test03-summary.xlsm']

for (<dirpath>, <dirnames>, <filenames>) in walk (<mypath>):
    FilenameList.extend(filenames)
    break

#This list will contain all the test numbers
IntegerList = []

#This loop will go through all filenames and filter the testnumbers and appand them to Integerlist
for file in FilenameList:
      for item in File:
        try:
            IntegerList.append(float(t))
        except ValueError:
          pass

#This will print the highest test number
print(max(IntegerList))
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the problem is that the number of files are not the same in each folder. it could be 3,4 or 5 files in each folder! I will edit my main question.

Comment: You can write a loop that goes trough each file of a folder, gimmi a second and i will write some code for it.

Comment: I added the code! This will loop trough all the files in the apointed folder

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to iterate over the required files, than use `sorted` to sort the list ascendent or descendent.

Using `ofunctions.file_utils` comes in handy to list only files with `.xlsm` extension.
Install the package using:

```
python -m pip install ofunctions.file_utils`
```

Here's the working code:

```
import ofunctions.file_utils

files = ofunctions.file_utils.get_files_recursive('.', ext_include_list='.xlsm')
files = sorted(files, reverse=True) # Remove reverse=True to achieve ASC ordering
print(files)
```

Result:

```
['.\\file-Test03-summary.xlsm', '.\\file-Test02-summary.xlsm', '.\\file-Test01-summary.xlsm']
```

Your highest number will then be `files[0]`.

You can add parameter `depth=1` to `get_files_recursive` in order to prevent descending into subdirectories.

Disclaimer: I am the author of ofunctions